# GWT - Getting the current size of an image

Tags: image, gwt, height, width, rescale

I use the GWT image class with a ClickHandler to trigger actions when specific areas of the image are clicked. In order to specify these areas, I use the image's dimensions. The problem occurs when you change the size of your browser window. While the image rescales nicely, the getWidth() and getHeight() methods still return the image's **original** size, not the size after rescaling.

Do you know a way to retrieve the current size of the image?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to be more concrete.

Comment: How are you "rescaling" the image?

Comment: I do not manually rescale the image. Either I make the browser window smaller by dragging its right bottom corner, or I just open the application with a mobile phone etc. Anyway, GWT scales the image down and it will be displayed smaller than it actually is. Now I need to get the dimensions of the image _as it is displayed_, preferably in pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.getElement().getOffsetWidgth() ? and .getOffsetHeight().

I think thats what you need.
That will return the current size of the element in the Dom, including any decorations like borders in the CSS.

Comment: Sadly this does not solve my problem, since the methods always return 0. I'll change the implementation, such that the problem is no longer valid. Thank you anyway!

Comment: That might be because the image isnt technically on the page yet at the time you are checking?
I have had that problem before - you might need to use Schedule.defered to wait till the browser has drawn everything onto the page. (annoying I know